# load tree structure using promises (promise within promise?)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to display a tree structure of items, my problem is how I should load this structure

Lets say I want a structure like this:

```
Parent1
  - Child1
  - Child2
Parent2
  - Child1
Parent3
  - Child1
```

When loading 'parents' I would do like this

```
var parents = [];

var promise = ParentService.queryParent();
promise.then(function(response){

    angular.forEach(response, function(item){
        // another promise here?
        parents.push(item);
    });

}, function(reason){
    console.log(reason);
});
```

But how should I load the 'children'? My first idea was to create another promise within the `forEach` of the first promise, but if I have a lot of parents, and a lot of children for each parent, this would not scale well (there's some big oh notation for this, the worst kind I guess)

How should I approach this issue, any ideas?

Edit: This is when I have the second promise within the first one

```
    var promise = ParentService.queryParent();
    promise.then(function(response){

        angular.forEach(response, function(item){
            parents.push(item);

            var promise2 = ChildService.queryChild(item.ID);
            promise2.then(function(response){

                angular.forEach(response, function(item){
                    children.push(item);
                });

            }, function(reason){console.log(reason);});

        });

    }, function(reason){console.log(reason);});
```

Issue: Doing this will display all parents, but not their children. The children are there, but it seems like the view can't keep up, what can be the reason for this?

Comment: is it a two level tree? or does the children have other children as well?

Comment: @HishamAbdel-Hafez at first I will have two levels, I'm thinking about loading more children when the parent is selected, but I will worry about that later

Comment: Please get your code working before worrying about its scalability. Then try it on larger inputs, and when you notice problems, ask us about *those*.

Comment: @Bergi well, my idea of using a promise within the forEach of the first one does work, but it's horribly slow when dealing with a lot of data. So I'm looking for another solution, or idea on how to approach it

Comment: @klskl: What exactly is horribly slow? Creating promises in a loop usually means that the actions run in parallel, which is as good as you get. If you are worried about it being too much data to load, the only thing you can do is to not load parts of it. However you didn't tell us what you need this for and how you want it to be, so we can hardly help you with that.